# Is that possible for Linux serial port input to buffer overflow?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver

If a program opened a serial port, and data is coming from the port in a speed higher that that the program's data-handling speed, then is it possible that the  kernel's serial buffer (I think it should be a tty buffer) gets overflow?  The program is handling the inbound data in a packet by packet wise, it needs some time to process each packet.  I checked the Linux tty_buffer.c, it seems that the kernel will always try to allocate new room for newly incoming characters if current buffer was full, but it's likely it also will check a port's buffer limit setting -- port->buf.mem_limit.  But I cannot find out the number of the limit in my system.

Does anyone have some info?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but very unlikely. If you need to protect against this you need to enable flow control, assuming the device supports it.

Comment: There are at least two buffers in the receiving serial terminal data path.  See http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html  The tty buffer is typically 4096 bytes.

Comment: I am tracing a software bug and my eyes is now looking at this point.  If the tty_buffer could overflow as I imaged, that could be the root cause of the issue I am analyzing. Currently, the serial port has only two wires, not hardware flow control.

Comment: Easily at high speeds and small FIFOs. There are several ways to mitigate, but until it’s not a real time OS, it’s impossible to avoid completely. Serial port communication requires a high profile CPU to serve and quite low latency from interrupt controller.